# JQuery: Multiple thumbnail scrollers without JavaScript duplication

Tags: jquery, scroll, thumbnails, code-duplication

I've been working on a thumbnail auto scrolling script.
Could anyone suggest how I could have *multiple* versions of the scroller without having to duplicate the JavaScript. It would be great if I could make the code generic, but somehow specify the ID's of DIVS in which the thumbnail scroller is to work, maybe in a variable. Help would be very much appreciated! :)

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gaelen/annUQ/) it is on JSFiddle.

Here is what the JavaScript looks like:

```
$(function() {
    buildThumbs();

    function buildThumbs() {
        $('div.album').each(function() {
            var width = 0;

            var wrapper = $(this).find('.st_thumbs_wrapper');
            wrapper.find('.st_thumbs a').each( function() {
                width += $(this).outerWidth(true);
            });

            var thumbs = $(this).find('.st_thumbs');
            thumbs.css('width', width + 'px');

            makeScrollable(thumbs, wrapper);
        });
    }

    function makeScrollable(thumbs, wrapper) {
        var width = wrapper.innerWidth();

        wrapper.scrollLeft(0);

        var leftBuffer = 200;
        var rightBuffer = 200;

        //When user move mouse over menu
        wrapper.unbind('mousemove').bind('mousemove', function(e) {
            var xPos = e.pageX - wrapper.offset().left - leftBuffer;
            var xMax = wrapper.innerWidth() - rightBuffer;
            if(xPos > 0 && xPos < xMax) {
                var perc = xPos / (xMax - leftBuffer);
                var scrollAmt = thumbs.outerWidth(true) - wrapper.innerWidth();
                wrapper.scrollLeft(perc * scrollAmt);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the absolute positioning from your CSS. Works fine.

http://jsfiddle.net/kFDMN/

If you need positioning, then you'll need to use it on an additional container, or use `wrapAll('<div>')` in your jQ to add it dynamically.

Comment: Thanks. Great. I didn't realise it would be that simple!

Comment: Hi Dawson. I think I do need positioning, because when I insert this into a CSS/JavaScript concertina menu, it doesn't work. I tried putting it in a container DIV with absolute positioning, but that didn't work either. How do I insert the `wrapAll('<div>')` into my JQ?

Comment: Here's a 'down and dirty' `wrapAll()` example applied to your main wrap: http://jsfiddle.net/kFDMN/1/. And a link to the jQ reference library, if you need another example/explanation - http://api.jquery.com/wrapAll/ - pretty straightforward function.

Comment: Thanks, the `wrapAll` is great. I inserted it into the accordion menu without any problem.Sorry if I'm asking too much from you, (no need to respond if you fell that's the case), but

Comment: How would I align the entire menu to the right? I want the thumbs to build from the right side of the page so that if there are only a few, they are aligned right. I tried `float:right` in the `.st_thumbs` css class  but then the auto-scrolling doesn't work. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kFDMN/2/) is the code with fewer thumbnails. Increase the window width to see what I mean. Your help is much appreciated :)

Comment: you're going to want to keep your _thumbs and _a together. Floating them differently is going to break things, as `float` removes elements from the document flow.